# How to Import This XYZ format file

Tags: import, chemistry

Here is the .XYZ format file [NP3D.XYZ](http://comsics.usm.my/tlyoon/teaching/ZCE111_1516SEM2/data/NP3D.xyz)

Somehow i cannot import this file.It return an error box :- "Cannot Import Data As XYZ Format."

it contains 1000 snapshot of 10 Carbon particles coordinate moving in a box that i have to visualise.

Comment: Is the pastebin ok? Please contemplate @OleksandrR. comment verry well!

Comment: from the wikipedia page  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XYZ_file_format  "There is no formal standard and several variations exist"

Comment: I'm wondering where do you get the simulation data from?

Comment: Also, what are the units in that file? If angstroms then those atoms are **very** close together

Comment: I really think you need to find out what units these are in, most of the time the units are angstroms, and that is what MMA assumes. Also, it will try to draw bonds between close atoms, which I don't think you want here at all.  Figure out he units, and whether you want bonds and then we can help give a better solution.

Comment: maybe far more smaller than armstrong. and i think it does not have bond because it only particles is moving according to the coordinate. i already make a simulation by using `imglist = 
  ImportString[ExportString[#, "Table"], "XYZ"] & /@ 
   Partition[StringSplit[Import["NP3D23.xyz", "Text"], "\n"], 12];` then `nlast = Length[imglist];

Manipulate[imglist[[i]], {i, 0, nlast}] @JasonB` but the bond still there

Answer (score 7):

It does not work because of different data elements, compare

```
Import["ExampleData/caffeine.xyz"]
```

[image]

with data structure

[image]

and your data structure:

[image]

but change it to:

[image]

with

```
Import["NP3D.xyz"]
```

you will get:

[image]

full data looks like

[image]

---

You can make an animation with these snapshots:

```
data1 = StringRiffle[#, "\n"] & /@ 
   Split[ReadList["/Users/xslittlegrass/Downloads/NP3D.xyz", 
      "String"], #2 =!= "10" &][[All, 3 ;; -1]];

data = ParallelMap[ImportString[#, "XYZ"] &, data1]; // AbsoluteTiming

Export["~/Downloads/1.gif", data[[46 ;; 146]]]
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way for me to change whole data structure from start until end? @Louis

Comment: Is this ok? http://pastebin.com/CPWBAPnj

Comment: It's not okay to just remove the intermediate lines. There are 1000 different structures recorded in the file; drawing these all on top of each other is not what OP wants. Rather, some `Manipulate` (or something like that) to step through each structure is what is desired. But, OP should be able to sort this out for themselves IMO.

Comment: @OleksandrR., i guess you are right, feel free to edit or answer on your self

Comment: Thank You @Louis . the new data u give is nice

Answer (score 2):

This will split the text into chunks and plot them as molecular plots,

```
imglist = ImportString[ExportString[#, "Table"], "XYZ"] & /@
   Partition[
    StringSplit[
     Import["http://comsics.usm.my/tlyoon/teaching/ZCE111_1516SEM2/\
data/NP3D.xyz", "Text"], "\n"], 12];
```

But, those carbon atoms sure are close together....

```
imglist[[405]]
```

[image]

Maybe the units are not angstroms?